# Всплывающая подсказка в AppCompatEditText (androidx.*)

Tags: android, android-edittext, androidx

Я использую виджет `AppCompatEditText`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_body"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/tooltip_body"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/et_title" />
```

и хочу, чтобы при наборе текста в этом виджете подсказка (hint) всплывала наверх, как Title в примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если я устанавливаю просто `android:hint`, то подсказка показывается только до тех пор, пока не начался ввод текста, и после набора текста наверх не переходит. 
Со старой библиотекой Support Library этого можно было добиться, поместив `EditText` внутрь тега `<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>`,
а можно ли как-нибудь сделать это только с помощью Jetpack (`androidx.*`)?

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо, да, это именно то, что я искала! Нашла в пакете com.google.android.material.textfield. Оформите как ответ, обязательно приму)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно  [списку AndroidX refactoring](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor) библиотеку поддержки *support.design* (в который входит виджет `TextInputLayout`) переместили в библиотеку *com.google.android.material* пакета androidX

Answer (score 0):

Новый макет TextInputLayout из библиотеки Android Design Support Library добавляет немного красоты к текстовому полю. Когда пользователь начинает вводить текст в текстовом поле, то подсказка, заданная в этом компоненте, всплывает над ним в специальном TextView.

Пример:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/textinputlayout.php

Comment: если внимательно прочитать вопрос, то автор вполне в курсе, что это за виджет и спрашивает совсем о другом